# sessionStorage if value already exist

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

Found pretty good script for showing recently viewed products using sessionStorage. There is only one problem: each product could be stored and showed multiple times.

Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r77oozh8/

There should be one more IF to check if current product is already in storage, something like this:

```
// check if product already in storage
if(!productExistsInStorage()) {

    var currentCount = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("storedCount"));

    // add to storage
    sessionStorage.setItem(currentCount.toString(), JSON.stringify(productInfo()));

    // update storedCount var by one
    sessionStorage.setItem("storedCount", (currentCount + 1).toString());

}
```

I tried to make it, but without any success.

Any tips how not to save product data if it was already set in sessionStorage?

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this post after I've looked it up myself.

```
if ("value" in sessionStorage) {
    alert("yes");
}
else {
    alert("no");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting separate items in `sessionStorage` for each product, i would set them all in one array. That would make it easier to check if it already exists:

```
var currentItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('products'));
var currentProduct = productInfo();
if (currentItems.filter(function(p){return p.productURL == currentProduct.productURL}).length == 0) {
// add
}
```

Comment: Error log "sessionStorage.get is not a function"

Comment: Typo. Should be `getItem`

Comment: Well, thanks, but it's not possible for me to rewrite code as you suggested (save products data to array). I'm too noob for this :/

Answer (score -1):

Why not check is session storage for that item is null or not?

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem("storedCount") === null)
{
//do something
}
```

Even better make a function that you can pass the name of an item to to check it.

```
function doesStorageExist(item)
{

if(sessionStorage.getItem(""+item) === null)
{
//do something
}

}
```

Comment: Because the OP cares about the content of the item. The ID is constantly incremented.

Comment: The question makes no sense. Are you trying to just increment a count variable in session storage?!

Comment: The way i understood the question, the user can add items to their storage. Each time, it's given a new ID, even if the actual item already exists. Therefore, the content needs to be checked, not just the number.

Comment: OK so check to see the content exists...
Keep a count as the item ID

Comment: Right, that's more like what my answer does. Yours doesn't.

Comment: You have an answer?!
All you wrote is the ID is incremented. He asked how to check a session storage value exists